# Adding text to UITextView using interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I have a `textview`, and i have set the `height` to 600 in `interfacebuilder`. Then i pasted one big article (which might have had over 5000+ characters). The application scrolls and every bit of text can be seen properly.

The problem i have is that, i need to have a heading (bold and increace font size) and then the body of the text to appear with a lesser font size etc. How can i do this in `interface builder` ?

If it is unable to be done using `IB`, then how can i do it programatically ?

Answer (score 1):

The text in a `UITextView` will all have the same font, style, and size. You'll need a `UILabel` or some other text widget to display anything differently. You could use a `UIWebView` and then the world is your oyster.

Also, it will be better design to put your article text into a text file, load it up at runtime, and put the text then into your text view, like so:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                          endcoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                              error:&error];

if (text == nil) {
   [self doSomethingUsefulWith:error];
} else {
   myTextView.text = text;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the implementation of the method `getTheFilePathSomehow` ? and will i be able to bold, change font of the text if i do it this way ?

Comment: So if the content is in a text file. How will the program know, which sentence to Bold or Italics ?

Comment: That is a design question particular to your app. It's basically the reason we're all here telling you that perhaps HTML in a UIWebView is the way to go...

Comment: Note: `UITextView` can now use attributed text. So, multiple font size, color, etc. can be used inside a `UITextView` in InterfaceBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

you can reader as html code using **UIWebview**

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL;
```

and code the whole message then wrap the link to

```
[webView.loadHTMLString:@"<h1>heading</h1><h2>test smaller</h2>" baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

That can not be done in either IB or programmatically. The `UITextView` may only display text using an attribute for the entire content.

The most simple solution for attributed text is using a `UIWebView` (as well drafted by a adali's answer).

Alternatives would be using multiple `UITextView`s or `UILabel`s.

The most sophisticated way to cover your needs would be using `CoreText`. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) for more.